# Declare an Array of ArrayLists of certain object

Tags: java, arraylist

i need to make an array of arraylists of an object.

i have tried two ways , but i can't access object's properties from the array elements.

i've tried :

```
     ArrayList<Word>[] SubList = (ArrayList<Word>[])new ArrayList(MainList.size());
```

AND :

```
    ArrayList<Word>[] SubList= new ArrayList[MainList.size()];
```

AND:

```
           ArrayList<Word>[] SubList= (ArrayList<Word> [])new ArrayList[MainList.size()];
```

What i would like to do is to call a method from the object inside the array

like this :

```
    SubList[0].get(0).method();
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Why not use an ArrayList of an ArrayList?

Comment: i can use that , i just don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid working with low level Arrays and to preserve type safety, you could make a list of a list

```
List<List<Word>> listOfList = 
         new ArrayList<List<Word>>(new ArrayList<List<Word>>());
```

Which you then could access like

```
Word word = listOfList.get(0).get(0);
```

Comment: why you use this syntax: ` new ArrayList<List<Word>>(new ArrayList<List<Word>>())`?   .... and not ` new ArrayList<List<Word>>()`?

Comment: this seems very good ,  i have defined many ArrayLists in my Code , do i need to re-write them as Lists? in order to store them in this list of lists

Comment: @user1203861, that sounds like a good idea since Lists are easier to work with than arrays.

Comment: @dantuch, the reason is that I inline the creation of the second list to keep it a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

**Generally you cannot do that, because it is not type safe.**

See [Angelika Langer's Gererics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104) about the issue (and some [additional notes here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Papers/JavaGenerics/ArraysInJavaGenerics.htm)).

What you can do however, is writing code without using generics and type-casting each time. You'll get a lot of warnings but note that you are sailing on dangerous waters indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support Arrays of generics very well. However, if you insist on having the top-level structure being an `Array` type object, you could work around this limitation by creating a new class that extends the generic:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Test {
    private static class StringArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringArrayList[] sublist = new StringArrayList[1];
        int stringLength;

        sublist[0] = new StringArrayList();
        sublist[0].add("Hello");

        stringLength = sublist[0].get(0).length();
        System.out.println(stringLength);
    }
}
```

It's not pretty, but it works. It's fine for a personal project but might be a bit too cluttered and C++-like for a large Java enterprise ;)